# .NET MVC - JQuery AJAX that retrieves a Partial View sometimes returns a 404 error, can't pinpoint issue behind this

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I've created a form that dynamically adds partial views that consists of form fields via button clicks (there are unique buttons for each of the partial view - one is for a record request, the other, a reference request). The user can add as many record or reference requests they'd like to the original form.

The retrieval of the HTML from the partial views is done through JQuery's Ajax. However, it doesn't work consistently. Sometimes, if I open the form, when clicking on one of the two buttons, it returns a 404 error. However, if I refresh (or open at another time), it fires and posts the results w/o any issues - it works beautifully when the server is able to return the data. But of course, I need this to work consistently and can't figure out what's going on here.

I've tried adjusting the ajax settings - changed the type from GET to POST and tried the pathway for where the partial view resides via a @Html.UrlAction helper, but to no avail. I've Googled this but don't see anything dealing with off-on AJAX failures re: partial views

HTML for original form, clipped for brevity, View/Home/Index.cshtml

```
<div class="customer">
            <form>
                <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "required" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LastName, new { @class = "required" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "required" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PhNbr, new { @class = "required" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PhNbr, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PhNbr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="request">
            <h2 class="topspacing-med btmspacing-med">Request Details</h2>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg btn-block btmspacing-med" id="addRecord">Add New Record Request</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg btn-block" id="addRef">Add New Reference Request</button>
            <div id="displayForm"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

example partial view - View/Partials/_RecordRequestForm.cshtml

```
@Html.BeginForm("SubmitRecord", "Home"){
<div id="record">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Record Request</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Comments)
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Comments, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="btn-toolbar justify-content-between" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
                <div class="btn-group float-right mt-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group" ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Save" />
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

the AJAX script - in the index file

```
        $("#addRecord").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                //url: "../Views/Partials/_RecordRequestForm.cshtml",
                url:"RenderNewRecordRequestForm",
                dataType: "html",
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#displayForm').append(result);
                    hideButtons();
                    count++;
                    console.log(count);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                    console.log(thrownError);
                },

            });
        });
```

Action method for rendering partial in Home controller

```
 private string PartialViewPath(string name)
        {
            return $"~/Views/Partials/Home/{name}.cshtml";
        }

        public ActionResult RenderNewRecordRequestForm()
        {
            return PartialView(PartialViewPath("_RecordRequestForm"));
        }
```

the _Layout file has the Jquery reference at the bottom

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Again, this works great when the AJAX returns the data, but it's not working consistently. Need to understand why it's failing at times.

Comment: 404 error is Page Not Found error. So if you are having that error it seems that the partial view is included in different pages and the controllers for those pages might be different. So I suggest you use your url as `@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))/Controller/RenderNewRecordRequestForm`

Comment: @Bosco - actually, the controller with the action method to retrieve the partial view is in the Home controller. You're right, the partial is in a different folder but I use a helper method to set the pathway to the file in the controller:

```private string PartialViewPath(string name)
        {
            return $"~/Views/Partials/{name}.cshtml";
        }
``` 
I've used this int he past without any issues (but not for Ajax) so I'm surprised this would be the source of the problem. Additionally, it does work if I refresh the site a few times.

Comment: try to add partial view in share folder so when you return partial view from controller so it will check in share folder also

Comment: @mustufa - unfortunately, am still having issues w/ the ajax performing consistently. Still can't find the page some times, can find it other times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this what worked after all - using: url: '@Url.Action("RenderNewRecordRequestForm", "Home")', in the Ajax settings. I thought I had tried this before (or maybe there was a typo in the last go around) but now the Ajax is able to locate the file via the correct Action Method in the correct Controller. All is well (so far). –